# How to de-identify specific words in the text by list using apache spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, text-classification, document-classification

***I want to identify those sentences that have some specific words.
as you will see in my code i have defined some terms and sentences. I want to print all those sentences that have these defined terms.***

****Here is my code:****

```
import scala.math.random
import org.apache.spark._
object Clasifying {

def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Classification")
.setMaster("local")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val terms = Array("this", "is", "my", "pen")

val sentences = Array("this Date is mine", 
                  "is there something", 
                  "there are big dogs",
                  "The Date is mine", 
                  "there may be something", 
                  "where are pen", 
                  "there is a dog",
                  "there are big cats",
                  "I am not able to to do it")

val rdd = sc.parallelize(sentences) // create RDD
val keys = terms.toSet            // words required as keys.

val result = rdd.flatMap{ sen => 
                val words = sen.split(" ").toSet; 
                val common = keys & words;       // intersect
                common.map(x => (x, sen))        // map as key -> sen
            }
            .groupByKey.mapValues(_.toArray)     // group values for a key
            .collect

println("*********************************")
result.foreach(println)
println("*********************************")
sc.stop()
}
```

My Code give the result as :

```
*********************************
(pen,[Ljava.lang.String;@4cc76301)
(this,[Ljava.lang.String;@2f08c4b)
(is,[Ljava.lang.String;@3f19b8b3)
*********************************
```

While I want a result like:

```
 *********************************
 {this, is,(this Date is mine)}
 {is,(is there something)}
 {is,(the Date is mine)}
 {is,(is there something)}
 {pen,where are pen)}
 *********************************
```

Thanks in advance, as I am new to spark and stack Overflow so excuse me on error and feel free to edit my question.

*One more thing i want that what if instead of defining simple terms and sentences i use some real terms.txt file and ducoment.txt for sentences? how will be the code for such satuation?*

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on the size of your documents and the size of your wordlist.

If you're able to keep the full wordlist in memory and a complete document in every container, then you can do it very easily through an UDF with just a map.
If not, then you can first collect all the words from each document, and join them with your wordlist to get the words to be "anonymised".

Be careful not to burn yourself though :D

Comment: obtusely the size of both documents will be huge